# Container managed transcation (CMT) in hibernate + EJB

Tags: java, hibernate, jta

The [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d0e1472) says:

> With CMT, transaction demarcation is declared in session bean deployment descriptors, rather than performed in a programmatic manner.

but I can't find any complete example on how to do this.

This is what I have in mind my code should look like:

```
@Stateless
public class Dao{

  @Inject // or some other annotation
  private SessionFactory factory;

  public void doDaoStuff(){
    Object obj = factory.getCurrentSession().get(Entity.class, "Id");
    // do something with obj
    return;
  }
}
```

It is free from all the boilerplate that hibernate has as transaction should be started, committed and roll backed by container.

So, Is it possible to do this? Although the documentation says that required declarations should be specified in **bean deployment descriptors**, doing it with annotations would be great.

Comment: Like the `@Transactional` annotation?

Comment: yes like the `@Transactional` annotation but that's from spring and I cant use it. Doesn't EJB has and equivalent annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaEE environments Hibernate can use the CMT (Container Managed Transaction) strategy which will bind hibernate transactions with the underlying JTA transaction eliminating the need to manually begin, commit and rollback transactions. Example [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#transactions-api-cmt-example).

However, there are problems:

1. This doesn't work in all Java EE Containers. Newer versions of Websphere are not supported and quoting from the [source code of hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/internal/WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java) - *WebSphere, however, is not a sane JEE/JTA container...*
2. This restricts to one session one transaction idiom. Thus during the invocation of a EJB business method, there can be only one JTA or Hibernate transaction.

Luckily, using [CDI](http://cdi-spec.org/), and some custom interceptors this can be solved and a lot of Hibernate boilerplate can be removed. I wrote a sample on [github](https://github.com/vivekkr12/cdi-hibernate).

This approach creates a wrapper for [Hibernate SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) and provides most commonly used APIs. Using CDI, [`@RequestScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html) Sessions are opened and closed automatically. Transactions are managed using an Interceptor. `@RequestScoped` ensures one `Session` per request so sessions aren't shared among multiple requests.

```
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.StatelessSession;

@RequestScoped
public class MySessionFactory implements SessionFactoryTemplate{

    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;// Inject after creating the singleton instance

    private Session currentSession;

    public Session openSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession(){
        if(currentSession == null){
            currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return currentSession;
    }

    public StatelessSession openStatelessSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void closeSession(){
        if(currentSession!=null && currentSession.isOpen()) {
            currentSession.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is then injected in database layer and used to obtain sessions.

```
import org.ares.cdi.hibernate.sf.MySessionFactory;
import org.ares.cdi.hibernate.interceptors.Transactional;

public class Dao {

  @Inject
  private MySessionFactory sf;

  public void get(int id){
    sf.getCurrentSession().get(clazz,id);
  }

  @Transactional
  public void add(Object entity){
    sf.getCurrentSesion().add(entity);
  }
}
```

Transactions are managed by `TranscationManager` interceptor and declared by `@Transactional` annotation.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

import org.ares.cdi.hibernate.sf.MySessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.resource.transaction.spi.TransactionStatus;

@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionManager {

    @Inject
    private MySessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object handleTransaction(InvocationContext context) throws Exception{
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            return context.proceed();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        finally{
            if(tx.getStatus().equals(TransactionStatus.ACTIVE)){
                try{
                    tx.commit();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    tx.rollback();
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Transactional {



}
```

Answer (score 0):

EJB methods are transactional by default.

You can tweak their behavior using the [TransactionAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) annotation.

You can read more about CMT here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions003.htm#BNCIJ

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions.htm#BNCIH

Answer (score 0):

Your Typical example would be like--

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;

    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) 
    @Stateless(..)
    public class YourBean{

            @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)  // if in case you wanted to use 'existing' transaction
             public void DoStuff(){
               }

    }
```

And in your server configurations you require below tag under `<enterprise-beans>`

```
<transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
```